# passing parameter : Objective javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Objective javascript even I had a good amount of experience in Javascript. How do I pass my parameters to the calc closure here?

```
var calc = (function() {
    var a = 5;
    var b = 0;
    return {
        add: function() {
            return a + b;
        },
        subtract: function() {
            return a - b;
        },
        multiply: function() {
            return a * b;
        },
        divide: function() {
            if (b != 0) return a / b
            else {
                alert('division by zero');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})();​

    console.log(calc.divide());
```

I want to pass the parameters to calc like (calc.multiply(10,20));

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can I just say: 'indentation is a wonderful thing'?

Comment: I believe the standard is to return `NaN` in cases of division by zero. But, if you are intending the explicit validation, I suppose the alert is fine.

Answer (score 2):

According to your call method `calc.multiply(a, b)`: There should be like this:

```
var calc = (function() {
    return {
        add: function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        },
        subtract: function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        },
        multiply: function(a, b) {
            return a * b;
        },
        divide: function(a, b) {
            if (b != 0) return a / b
            else {
                alert('division by zero');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})();

console.log(calc.divide(20, 2));
```

Comment: Is there a need for the IIFE? I'd say no.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
var calc = (function() {
    var a = 5;
    var b = 0;
    return {
        add: function() {
            return a + b;
        },
        subtract: function() {
            return a - b;
        },
        multiply: function() {
            return a * b;
        },
        divide: function(n, d) {
            if (n != 0) return n / d
            else {
                alert('division by zero');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})();

alert(calc.divide(3, 4));​
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work for you:

```
var calc = (function() {
    var a = 5;
    var b = 0;

    return {
        add: function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        },
        subtract: function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        },
        multiply: function(a, b) {
            return a * b;
        },
        divide: function(a, b) {
            if (b !== 0) return a / b;
            else {
                alert('division by zero');
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
})();

console.log(calc.multiply(10, 10));
```

Edits I made were setting `a` and `b` parameters on each returned function, and making your comparison to zero safer on the `divide` function by making it strict.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Calc isn't a Javascript constructor -- it uses the module pattern instead.  No need for the uppercase function name or the new keyword.  It would work just 'as is' as a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

```
var calc = (function() {
    return {
        add: function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        },
        subtract: function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        },
        multiply: function(a, b) {
            return a * b;
        },
        divide: function(a, b) {
            if (b != 0) return a / b
            else {
                alert('division by zero');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})();​
```

Though I'd consider changing your alert to throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You either can give the parameters to `calc`, which returns an object to compute something with the two numbers, or you just make `calc` an object with functions that compute something. Your requirement `calc.multiply(10,20)` is for the second solution:

```
var calc = {
    add: function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    },
    subtract: function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    },
    multiply: function(a, b) {
        return a * b;
    },
    divide: function(a, b) {
        if (b != 0) return a / b
        alert('division by zero');
        return false;
    }
};​
```

Otherwise, for using `calc(10,20).multiply()`, it would be building the closure you already have, but with parameters instead of the two local constants:

```
function calc(a, b) {
    return {
        add: function() {
            return a + b;
        },
        subtract: function() {
            return a - b;
        },
        multiply: function() {
            return a * b;
        },
        divide: function() {
            if (b != 0) return a / b
            alert('division by zero');
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```